# compare 2 text columns and show difference in the third cell using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to compare 2 columns and I have to get the only difference for example

```
select * from table1

Column_1                column_2
----------------        ------------------
Swetha working          Swetha is working in Chennai
Raju 10th               Raju is studying 10th std
ranjith                 Ranjith played yesterday
how to play             how to play Cricket
My name is              my name is john
```

Output:

If words come in between it should also remove like row 1 and 2

```
Column_1                column_2                         column_3
----------------        ------------------               ------------------------
Swetha working          Swetha is working in Chennai     is in Chennai
Raju 10th               Raju is studying 10th std        is studying std
ranjith                 Ranjith played yesterday         played yesterday
how to play             how to play Cricket              Cricket
My name is              my name is john                  john
```

Comment: That's a more complex one. You'll have to split  `column_2` into tokens separated by space, and then search for those tokens in `column_1`, and finally group-concat the tokens not found in `column_1` with space as separator. I'll have a go - bear with me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much more complicated than your previous question.  You can break the first column into words and then substitute them individually in the second column.  To do that, though, you need a recursive CTE:

```
with words as (
      select t.*, s.*,
             max(s.seqnum) over (partition by t.id) as max_seqnum
      from t cross apply
           (select s.value as word,
                   row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
            from string_split(col1, ' ') s
           ) s
     ),
     cte as (
      select id, col1, col2,
             replace(' ' + col2 + ' ', ' ' + word + ' ', ' ') as result,
             word, seqnum, max_seqnum
      from words
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select cte.id, cte.col1, cte.col2,
             replace(cte.result, ' ' + w.word + ' ', ' '),
             w.word, w.seqnum, cte.max_seqnum
      from cte join
           words w
           on w.id = cte.id and w.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select id, col1, col2, ltrim(rtrim(result)) as result
from cte
where max_seqnum = seqnum
order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f3f347cdeb12d1685fe4676ab2770c9) is a db<>fiddle.

I added an `id` so each row is uniquely defined.  If your version of SQL Server doesn't have the built-in `string_split()` function, you can easily find a version that does the same thing.

One trick that this uses is for handling the first and last words in the second column.  The code adds spaces at the beginning and end.  That way, all words in the string are surrounded by spaces, making it easier to replace only complete words.

Answer (score 1):

SQL 2016 definitely has string split.  This approach appends an extra space to either side of the split word from Column 2.

Data

```
drop table if exists #strings;
go
create table #strings(
   Id           int,
   Column_1     varchar(200),
   Column_2     varchar(200));
go
insert #strings(Id, Column_1, Column_2) values
(1, 'Swetha', 'Swetha is working in Chennai'),
(2, 'Raju', 'Raju is studying 10 std'),
(3, 'Swetha working', 'Swetha is working in Chennai'),
(4, 'Raju 10th', 'Raju is studying 10th std');
```

Query

```
declare
  @add_delim         char(1)=' ';

;with
c1_cte(split_str) as (
    select ltrim(rtrim(s.[value]))
    from
      #strings st
      cross apply
      string_split(st.Column_1, ' ') s),
c2_cte(Id, ndx, split_str) as (
    select Id, charindex(@add_delim + s.[value] + @add_delim, @add_delim + st.Column_2 + @add_delim), s.[value]
    from
      #strings st
      cross apply
      string_split(st.Column_2, ' ') s
    where
      st.Column_2 not like '%  %')
select 
Id, stuff((select ' ' + c.split_str
             from c2_cte c
             where c.Id = c2.Id and not exists(select 1 
                                               from c1_cte c1
                                               where c.split_str=c1.split_str)
             order by c.ndx FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [new_str]

from c2_cte c2
group by Id;
```

Results

```
Id  new_str
1   is in Chennai
2   is studying 10 std
3   is in Chennai
4   is studying std
```

Comment: Sorry I had to update.  It now works with stuff+xml

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution using `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG`

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a4f03bf4a2ea9fd94d80714ecf18c62b) working link

```
;WITH split_words
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Strings
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT VALUE
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(column_2, ' ')
        WHERE VALUE NOT IN (
                SELECT VALUE
                FROM STRING_SPLIT(column_1, ' ')
                )
        ) a
    )
SELECT *
    ,(
        SELECT sw.VALUE + ' ' [text()]
        FROM split_words sw
        WHERE sw.Column_1 = s.Column_1
            AND sw.Column_2 = s.Column_2
        FOR XML PATH('')
            ,TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') [difference]
FROM dbo.Strings s
```

---

For SQL version 2017+ where `STRING_AGG` is supported

```
SELECT b.Column_1
    ,b.Column_2
    ,STRING_AGG(b.VALUE, ' ')
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Strings
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT VALUE
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(column_2, ' ')
        WHERE VALUE NOT IN (
                SELECT VALUE
                FROM STRING_SPLIT(column_1, ' ')
                )
        ) a
    ) b
GROUP BY b.Column_1
    ,b.Column_2
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: `STRING_AGG` is 2017+, the OP is on 2016.

Comment: I agree, but we can find a lot of answers to join the rows.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This OP (and any reader who comes across this question because it's tagged [tag:sql-server-2016], and any reader who comes across it and needs to support that version or earlier) can't use your answer. If I was asking a question about how to disable the odometer on a 2004 Honda Civic, "I don't know, but here's how to do it on a 2007 Toyota Corolla!" isn't a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
-- your input 
input(column_1,column_2,column_3) AS (
          SELECT 'Swetha working','Swetha is working in Chennai','is in Chennai'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Raju 10th','Raju is studying 10th std','is studying std'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ranjith','Rantith played yesterday','played yesterday'
UNION ALL SELECT 'how to play','how to play Cricket','Cricket'
UNION ALL SELECT 'My name is','my name is john','john'
)
,
-- need a series of integers
-- you can also try to play with the STRING_SPLIT() function
i(i) AS (
          SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 2
UNION ALL SELECT 3
UNION ALL SELECT 4
UNION ALL SELECT 5
)
,
-- you can also try to play with the STRING_SPLIT() function
unfound_tokens AS (
  SELECT
    i
  , column_1
  , column_2
  , TOKEN(column_2,' ',i) AS token
  FROM input CROSS JOIN i
  WHERE TOKEN(column_2,' ',i) <> ''
    AND CHARINDEX(
          UPPER(TOKEN(column_2,' ',i))
        , UPPER(column_1)
      ) = 0
)
SELECT 
  column_1
, column_2
, STRING_AGG(token ,' ') AS column_3
FROM unfound_tokens
GROUP BY
  column_1
, column_2
-- out     column_1    |           column_2           |         column_3         
-- out ----------------+------------------------------+--------------------------
-- out  My name is     | my name is john              | john
-- out  Swetha working | Swetha is working in Chennai | is Chennai
-- out  how to play    | how to play Cricket          | Cricket
-- out  Raju 10th      | Raju is studying 10th std    | is studying std
-- out  ranjith        | Rantith played yesterday     | Rantith played yesterday
```

Comment: TOKEN is a SSIS function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/token-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the results, while using STRING_AGG or STRING_SPLIT, will preserve the ordering of the words...

Just look over this query that give a different ordering :

```
WITH 
SS1 AS
(SELECT Id, SS.value AS COL1
 FROM   #strings
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Column_1, ' ') AS SS
),
SS2 AS
(SELECT Id, SS.value AS COL2
 FROM   #strings
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Column_2, ' ') AS SS
),
DIF AS
(
SELECT Id, COL2 AS COL
FROM   SS2
EXCEPT
SELECT Id, COL1
FROM   SS1
)
SELECT DIF.Id, Column_1, Column_2, STRING_AGG(COL, ' ')
FROM   DIF
       JOIN #strings AS S ON S.Id = DIF.Id
GROUP  BY DIF.Id, Column_1, Column_2;
```

You must try with a very huge amount of data to see if the queries that have been given, will not have a side effect like the unconsistent ordering (I am pretty sure that no consistent order will appear due to parallelism....)

So the only way to preserve a consistent ordering is to create a recursive query that add an indiced value of the word in the sentence...